# side panel: not able to set side panel properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script as below to view side panel, on click. But its not showing side panel, its redirecting to the `href` link page which I want in side panel.

**Script:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").append("<div id='divSmallBoxes'></div>");
        $("body").append("<div id='divMiniIcons'></div><div id='divbigBoxes'></div>");
        $(".harjeet").pageslide({ direction: "left" });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="secondary.php" class="harjeet" title="User">harjeet</a>
```

Comment: where is `pageslide` coming from? it's not a native jQuery method

Comment: i got this code from net.
Can you help with proper native jQuery method for side panel.

Comment: There is no native jQuery method for "sliding", you can animate instead (depending on what you want to achieve). Can you post more markup (NOT the entire markup), and explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Notice that a `<script>` with a `src` attribute is not allowed to have script inside. Are you only showing this for convenience?